# "Bounce to the beat" meaning in this context

Tags: spoken-english

I was reading about acting out while saying a rhyme and I found this line:

> Gently **bounce baby to the beat.**

Being a learner I suppose:

"Bouncing **to the beat"** is the same pattern as "dancing **to the song"**

Am I correct?

Now,

The word **bounce** generally means **move back after hitting something.**

I am rather confused as to what the **bouncing a baby** actually mean.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [*March **to the beat** of a different drum / drummer*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22march+to+the+beat%22)

Answer (score 1):

The image is of a ball bouncing on the ground repeatedly. You lift the baby up and down, or jog them up and down on your knee, in time to the beat.